# How to correlate a dynamic value in the first request of script loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have recorded following script snippet:

```
Action()
{

    /*Click on Continue to this website*/

    /*Login*/

    web_url("startSSO.ping",
        "URL=https://e4.pncie.com/sso/idp/0LEMc/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping",
        "TargetFrame=",
        "Resource=0",
        "RecContentType=text/html",
        "Referer=",
        "Snapshot=t1.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        EXTRARES,
        "URL=/favicon.ico", ENDITEM,
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("ClaimCenter.do",
        "Action={P_url}",
        "Method=POST",
        "TargetFrame=",
        "RecContentType=text/html",
        "Referer=https://e4.pncie.com/sso/idp/0LEMc/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping",
        "Snapshot=t2.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        ITEMDATA,
        "Name=SAMLResponse", "Value=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"
        "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"
        "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"
        "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"
        "8L3NhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlPg==", ENDITEM,
        EXTRARES,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/header_bg.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/modetabs_bgd.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/toolbar_bgd.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/menu_claim_search.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/unsaved_left_off.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/unsaved_middle.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/unsaved_right.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/btn2_left.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/btn2_1px.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/btn2_right.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabOn_1px.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabOn_left.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/menu-arrow-down-on.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabOn_right.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabOff_left.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabOff_1px.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/menu-arrow-down.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabOff_right.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabDS_1px.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabDS_right.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/tabDS_left.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/infobar_bgd.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/actionButton_middle.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/actionButton_left.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/actionButton_right.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/leftNav_select.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        "URL=resources/Ocean/images/pagetitle_bgd.gif", "Referer={P_url}?inFrame=mainframe&r=44794921&__navigator_index=0", ENDITEM,
        LAST);
```

where above in the first request send to the server a dynamic value `"0LEMc"` is occuring in the URL; likewise in the 2nd request.How do I correlate it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. How do you know that the value is dynamic?  It looks like a directory structure to me.
2. If it is in the first request (and it is dynamic) then it is a value generated locally generated by the client.   Most of these first call dynamic items are a unique session indicator based upon a 13 digit clock tick since epoch.   This five digit value of 0LEMc does not seem to correspond to a time value.  Have you asked the developer of the client application for insight?

Comment: Hi James, the value "0LEMc" changes every time I recorded the script; the rest of the URL remains same. Other values are "DQQK3", "2sc3k" & so on.Here SSO refers to Single Sign On.In the runtime viewer the first page shows the following message "Page Expired : To protect privacy and enhance security, the page you are trying to access is no longer available.Powered by Ping Identity". The rest of the script runs fine.I'm trying to get in contact with the developer of the client application & will post ASAP.

Comment: FYI, the run time viewer is not a full browser.   Consider the logs as authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your browser, obviously you don't make up this URL each time correct? You probably open a static login link that redirects to that one. Download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and have a look at what re-directs are happening.

Comment: DeutscherDon't understand what you mean by " make up this URL each time". The URL Address of the AUT(Application Under Test) is

Comment: already written at the time of recording (in the "Start Recording Dailog Box" after selecting the protocols) through Loadrunner by me.The Loadrunner then launches the website.

Comment: OK, forget about the recording for a minute. So when a user opens this website, say www.example.com. Does the user initiate the request (ie, via clicking login) or is this "SSO Ping" performed by AJAX without the user doing anything?

Comment: When I Click on "Continue to this website" as mentioned in the comments I automatically get a  dialog box showing "Connecting to e4.pncie.com" which asks for Username & a Password. I then log into this application/website & reach the Homepage.

Comment: Yes I understood what you mean by "make up this URL each time".I click on one static link & then it redirects to e4.pncie.com where probably validation occurs & then I land on Homepage of Application/website.So, what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Just to confirm, what is the URL you are putting into the "Start Recording Dialog Box"?

Comment: That is a URL one won't be able to access from just any machine.Anyways the url is : https://casperfpoc.tent.trt.csaa.pri/cc/Claimcenter.do

Comment: Perfect. So the first step of your script should be calling this page, and you can insert a `web_reg_save_param` to save the link URL above. The best way to see how this is working is to view it in Firebug with the 'Net' Panel enabled. You will see that a HTTP 302 will be called which is a redirect. In LoadRunner you can capture this by having your first lines of your script as `web_url` with the page you mentioned above and it should automatically redirect to the above link. You can then capture it via a `web_reg_save_param`.

Comment: This might help - http://www.headwired.com/articles/timing-http-redirects-in-loadrunner/

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate five digit value("0LEMc") for your request to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm reviewing your answer, and while it seems right (I assume), it's rather short. Perhaps you could expand this with an explanation of how and why this works, or point out where the OP's error was, so that they can learn from the solution, rather than just apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `"web_reg_save_param_regexp()" function` to correlate the values.

For Example:

```
/* Correlation comment - Do not change! Original value='c9cb6401b8' Name ='CorrelationParameter' */
web_reg_save_param_regexp(
"ParamName=CorrelationParameter",
"RegExp=_wpnonce=(.*?)\">Log\\ Out",
SEARCH_FILTERS,
"Scope=Body",
"IgnoreRedirections=Yes",
"RequestUrl=*/wp-admin/*",
LAST);
```

You have to use Right boundary and Left Foundry values and store dynamic values into a parameter and do correlation as follows

```
web_url("startSSO.ping",
        "URL=https://e4.pncie.com/sso/idp/{value}/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping",
        "TargetFrame=",
        "Resource=0",
        "RecContentType=text/html",
        "Referer=",
        "Snapshot=t1.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        EXTRARES,
        "URL=/favicon.ico", ENDITEM,
        LAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some key points which need to be considered before analyzing dynamic values.

1. After recording the script, try to record it one more time in the same way.
2. When you compare these two created scripts, you will get to know what all values have changed in the second script. Those dynamic values can be treated with Correlation.

I would suggest to verify it once whether the value you are targeting is dynamic or common in other round of scripts.

If you are sure, then you can try conventional way of Manual correlation of values.
Try finding the value in response and just before the respective request, add web_reg_save_param parameter and fill all the LB, RB values.